# Как вывести похожие слова из нескольких файлов в один?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Есть код:

```
_all = []
with open('prob 1.txt', 'r') as a:
    a_list = a.read().split(' ')
    _all.append(a_list)
    with open('prob 2.txt', 'r') as b:
        b_list = b.read().split(' ')
        _all.append(b_list)
result = set(_all[0])
for s in _all[1:]:
    result.intersection_update(s)
with open('compare_out.txt', 'w', ) as ufill:
     for each in result:
         ufill.writelines(each + '\n')
```

Но он ничего не выводит
Не могу понять, где ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Здравствуйте, добавила описание

Comment: Не выводит по многим причинам. Например, intersection_update(s) оставляет только те элементы, которые есть в обоих множествах. А у вас таких элементов вообще нет, потому удаляется всё.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли это как-то исправить?

Comment: по каким критериям слова считаются похожими?

Comment: Если слово из файл2 находится в словосочетании из файл1. К примеру в файле2 есть слово Alinka, в файле1 есть helloAlinka, результат должен быть такой: helloAlinka, Alinka. Скрипт должен проверять на наличие слов из файл2 в файл1, и выписывать совпадения. Как-то так:)

Answer (score 0):

не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотите сделать?

если найти одинаковые слова в двух файлах, то у вас код как-то утяжелен и по идее должен выглядеть так:

```
with open('prob 1.txt', 'r') as file:
    data1 = set(file.read().split())

with open('prob 2.txt', 'r') as file:
    data2 = set(file.read().split())

result = data1.intersection(data2)

with open('compare_out.txt', 'w', ) as file:
     for each in result:
         file.writelines(each + '\n')
```

конечно по хорошему слова с большой и маленькой буквами будут разными словами, поэтому наверное стоит сначала все выделенные слова перевести в нижний регистр, дальше вопрос по словам, разделённым знаками препинания - их тоже надо обработать отдельно (например, заменить все знаки пробелами и потом только разделить на слова) и т.д.

Comment: Здравствуйте, добавила описание

Comment: т.е. требуется чтобы слова из файла 2 находились в словах из файла 1?

Comment: Требуется, чтобы  "похожие" слова из файл1 и файл2 сохранялись в файл3 через запятую, а все остальное откидывалось